# google map resize position_changed conflict

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I want to refresh panorama after resize the street view window, and use

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'resize', function() {
  var pos = panorama.getPosition();
  var p = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat(),pos.lng());
  panorama.setPosition(p);
```

});

it seems work, but when pin a new panorama position, it also resize the window and set the position to be old one, and crash.

Comment: What do you mean by 'and crash'? Is there an error message?

Comment: I through there are no `resize` event for panorama... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewEvents

Comment: 'crash' like the street view will repeatedly display two position panorama

Comment: panorama has 'resize' event, it works but conflict with 'position_changed', I  thought it may when 'position_changed' event trigger, the window also resize.